# Payment history showing only refunded and declined payments

Tags: cognito-forms

My payments used to say "paid" or "unpaid", now they say "declined" and "refunded". The refunded payments have already been processed in my bank account - from months ago.

What's going on?

Answer (score 1):

[Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) leverages Stripe for payment processing and is updated in realtime when changes are made in your Stripe account.  This means that payments that are refunded or partially refunded in Stripe will also show up immediately as refunded in Cognito Forms.

We will work with you via the support ticket you created to help you understand what happened, but here are two important things to consider when using Stripe:

1. Processed payments can be contested after the fact resulting in a chargeback.  These will appear as refunded in Cognito Forms.  You should receive notifications from Stripe if/when this type of activity occurs.
2. Stripe has great customer support to help with any payment questions/issues you may have.  You can contact them at: https://support.stripe.com/email

We will do what we can on our end to research this on your behalf.